# What arangement of $n$ points in the plane minimizes the dispersion of the distances between them?

Tags: geometry, statistics, optimization

If $n=3$ the solution is an equilateral triangle where all sides have the same length. In general, there are $N = \frac{n}2(n-1)$ distances between the points. Use the empirical coefficient of variation as a relative measure of dispersion of the distances $x_i$

$$v = \frac1{\bar{x}} \sqrt{\frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \qquad \bar{x} = \frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N x_i$$

Below are some arangements of four points and their values of $v$ (distances with the same length are coloured). I have not found an arangement for $n=4$ with a smaller variation than the square. It is possible to show that for two points at $(\pm 1,0)$ and the two other ones at $(0,\pm y)$ the minimum of $v$ occurs at $y = 1$.

$\hspace{4cm}$ [image]

For $n < 8$ the regular polygons seem to minimize the variation $v = P(n)$. After that it is better to place one point at the center and arange the others evenly around it like in the arangement on the right. In that case, call $v=Q(n)$

$$P(n) = \tan{\left( \frac\pi{2n} \right)} \sqrt{N - \cot^2{\left( \frac\pi{2n} \right)}} \qquad
Q(n) = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{n^2}2 - \left( \cot{\left( \frac\pi{2(n-1)} \right)} + 1 \right)^2}}{\cot{\left( \frac\pi{2(n-1)} \right)} + 1}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc|ccc} n & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline P(n) & 0.172 & 0.236 & 0.277 & 0.3066 & 0.328 & 0.345 & 0.359 \\ Q(n) & 0.268 & 0.269 & 0.287 & 0.3068 & 0.324 & 0.339 & 0.351 \end{array}$$

Are there better strategies for $n \to \infty$? And is there a way to prove an arangement is optimal for a given $n$?

Comment: @mathworker21 We need a relative measure of dispersion to make it independent of the size of the arangement. Otherwise we could just place all points on each other. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation

Comment: @mathworker21 $\overline{x}$ is not the average position but the average distance, it's a scalar.

Comment: @leonbloy ah, thnaks. i read question quickly and thought $x_i$ were the points

Comment: you can write a simulation where you start by placing points at random and then randomly move them around and see what will happen, probably manipulating one point per round (one with biggest sum of distances) will do the trick

Comment: BTW: if we pick two random points inside a circle, the ratio of the standard deviation of the distance and its mean is $0.33754$ . I'm not sure is this should be related to $v$.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312294065_Modeling_distances_between_humans_using_Taylor's_law_and_geometric_probability

Comment: Also, both $P(n)$ and $Q(n)$ tend to $\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{{{{\pi} }^{2}}-8}}{4} = 0.4834258476$ , hence this should be an upper bound for $v$

Answer (score 6):

Not quite an answer  (I'd be suprised if this problem can be solved analytically) but, I've playing a little:

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjgonzalez984/eavz6gso/42/show) lets you play for different values of $n$. The minimization algorithm (not optimized!) has a "temperature" parameter (kind of a simulated annealing), higher values lets you escape from local minima.

Empirically, my findings agrees with yours: for $n = 4 \cdots 7$ the regular polygons win. For $n=8, 9, 10, 11$ it's the polygon with a central point - but for $n=11$ the configuration with two internal points is a quite deep (but still suboptimal) local minimum.

For $n=12$, the configuration $(10,2)$ (two internal points) is the optimal one, but $(11,1)$ and $(9,3)$ are relevant competitors.

[image]

[image]

[image]

For larger $n$ things get more complicated, with many similar local mimima.

For example, for $n=21$, the first configuration here $(15,5,1)$ is the main attractor, but there are other three importal local minima, and the last one $(16,5)$ seems to be the optimal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For even larger values, the points tend to distribute all over the circle, as expected, but with higher concentration over the circumference.
For $n=300$ I get $v=0.4604068$. Not too far from the upper bound limit $0.4834258476$ (where all the points lie on the circumference).

[image]

Visually, this appears to support Anders Kaseorg's answer, points seem to correspond to the projection of a uniform distribution over a sphere.

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that, in the limit as $n → ∞$, the optimal distribution of points converges to some rotationally symmetric distribution, and optimize a numerical approximation of this distribution, we find outrageously strong numerical evidence that the distribution appears to be the one you get by orthogonal projection onto a plane from the uniform distribution on the surface of a sphere.

[image: plot]

(Plot of the predicted vs. optimized inverse CDF of the distance from the origin, normalized such that $\overline x = 1$.)

Consider the segment between two uniformly random points on the sphere of radius $r$ (before projection). Let $a$ be the cosine of the angle between the segment and the projection direction, and let $b$ be the cosine of the spherical angle between the points. Then $a$ and $b$ are independent uniformly random values between $-1$ and $1$. We can compute the planar distance between the projected points as $r\sqrt{1 - a^2}\sqrt{2 - 2b}$. So the mean planar distance is

$$\overline x = \frac14 \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 r\sqrt{1 - a^2}\sqrt{2 - 2b}\,da\,db = \frac{πr}{3},$$

and the coefficient of variation is

\begin{multline*}
v = \frac{3}{πr} \sqrt{\frac14 \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \left(r\sqrt{1 - a^2}\sqrt{2 - 2b} - \frac {πr}3\right)^2\,da\,db} \\
= \frac{\sqrt{12 - π^2}}{π} ≈ 0.464601123231588.
\end{multline*}

Comment: What do you mean by "inverse CDF" and how did you obtain the plot?

Comment: An [inverse CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Inverse_distribution_function_(quantile_function)) is a function that maps the uniform distribution on (0, 1) to a target distribution. I discretized the inverse CDF as a vector of 128 samples—this constitutes an approximation of the rotationally symmetric distribution as the union of 128 equally-weighted circles—and numerically optimized these radii to minimize the coefficient of variation. The observed optimum closely matches $F^{-1}(p) = r\sqrt{1 - (1 - p)^2}$, which is the inverse CDF of the projected sphere.